# ProgressDialog getting Dismissed before Toast appears from doInBackground method of AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I'm making a `JSON HTTP` request using `AsyncTask`. I have created a `ProgressDialog` in `onPreExecute()` and i'm dismissing it in `onPostExecute()`. The problem is, there is a Toast message in `diInBackground()`which shows the JSON `response` and `ProgressDialog` is being dismissed before the `Toast` appears, meaning `onPostExecute()` is being called before the `Toast` is generated. How can I dismiss it just before the `Toast` appears?

Here is my code.

```
private  class login extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
      private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute(){
          super.onPreExecute();
          // Create & Start Progress Dialog
          progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
          progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
          progressDialog.show();
      }
      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
          String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk";
          JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null,
                  new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                      @Override
                      public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                          try {

                                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                              }

                          }
                          catch (Exception e){
                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Server error!..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                          }


                      }
                  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
              @Override
              public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                  VolleyLog.e("from on error response Server Error..: ", error.getMessage());

              }
          });

          AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);

            return null;
      }
      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void v){
          // Terminate Progress Dialog
          progressDialog.dismiss();
      }
      }
```

Comment: how can you call Toast from background Thread ? I think this code wrong.

Comment: OK. But how do I access response object from onPostExecute() ? It's no longer accessible after doInBackground() has finished. (Do i need to set the Result as a JSONObject?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Need to write the Volley Request in Async Task. You can Directly Excute that task because internaly it's using thread. So Once you got response or Failure so u can close the dialog there it self. I guess it will helps you

```
 String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk";
      JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null,
              new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                  @Override
                  public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

      if(progressDialog.isShowing){
     progressDialog.cancel();
       }
                      try {

                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                          }

                      }
                      catch (Exception e){
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Server error!..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                      }


                  }
              }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
          @Override
          public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
              VolleyLog.e("from on error response Server Error..: ", error.getMessage());
  if(progressDialog.isShowing){
 progressDialog.cancel();
   }
          }
      });

      AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
```

I hope this will helps you And no need of AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {

                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                          }

                      }
                      catch (Exception e){
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Server error!..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                      }
```

This code completely wrong. **You can not add Toast from doInBackground.**  . You need to move this after dismiss dioalog

```
// Terminate Progress Dialog
      progressDialog.dismiss();
//Add your Toast here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dismiss the dialog manually after toast shows, with a TimerTask. You can see how to use TimerTask [HERE](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/activity/android-timertask-example/). You are using Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, so the toast will show for 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

dismiss the progressdialog inside response and error listener...no need to dismiss on post method

```
private  class login extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
  private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute(){
      super.onPreExecute();
      // Create & Start Progress Dialog
      progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
      progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
      progressDialog.show();
  }
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk";
      JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null,
              new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                  @Override
                  public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                      try {

                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                          }

                      }
                      catch (Exception e){
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Server error!..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      progressDialog.dismiss(); add this line

                      }


                  }
              }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
          @Override
          public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
              VolleyLog.e("from on error response Server Error..: ", error.getMessage());
      progressDialog.dismiss(); add this line

          }
      });

      AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);

        return null;
  }
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void v){
      // Terminate Progress Dialog
      //progressDialog.dismiss(); comment this line
  }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

**you want print toast message then you can use 
Handler.**

```
   Handler h = new Handler(this.getMainLooper());
                h.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //stopProgress 
                    }
                });
```